# How to programmatically work out the destination path for a Jekyll collection entry?

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to write a plugin for Jekyll that needs to iterate through collections and work out the final URL for each of the documents in a collection.

I can get the permalink for a collection from its metadata, but I'm presuming that Jekyll itself has code to correctly calculate the URL for a given collection document ... does anyone know how I can call it in order to get the correct URL rather than trying to parse the permalink myself?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that both the Jekyll::Page and Jekyll::Document classes include the url and relative_path attributes that I need so I can get it from there ...